# Getting status 403 with HttpUrlConnection but 200 with HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: httpurlconnection, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to get response code for site "https://www.applefcu.org/".
When I run the code with "HttpUrlConnection", I am getting status code as 403, but when I run the code with "HttpsUrlConnection", it gives status 200.

What can be the reason for this? 
and how do I identify when to run this code with "HttpUrlConnection" and when with "HttpsUrlConnection"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info is right there in the address.  If the URL says https:// use `HttpsUrlConnection`

Comment: okay ... thanks...
but what exactly is the problem that I got 403 with HttpUrlConnection and 200 with HttpsUrlConnection

Comment: An http connection will go to port 80 by default and https to 443.  The error tells you the server doesn't allow http connections on the https port.